# Calculate cell only when column header equals a certain value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

First time poster so any would be greatly appreciated.

I would like to perform calculations on a given row only when the column header contains a value.

```
Column A
**Name**
Column B
**Test 1**
Column C
**H1**
Column D
**H2**
Column E
**Test 2**
```

The above example will better explain what I'd like to do. I have a series of columns, some with test results and with homework results. Tests and Homework results can be in any order. What I would like to do is perform calculations such average, sum etc based on whether it is a homework or test. So that for example I would like to average all the homework results for a pupil (on a given row).

Is this possible and if so how. I am using Excel 2010 if that helps.

Comment: Maybe an example with figures will help describe your problem?

Comment: You can look for formulas like `SUMIF` or `SUMPRODUCT`. Why don't you give it a try and then post back with what you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SUMIF](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx) and [COUNTIF](https://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx) functions. Lets says your worksheet looks like this:

```
Name    Test 1  H1  H2  Test 2  
John    10      20  30  20
```

Then you can get these values:

```
No. of Tests    No. of H    Sum of Test Sum of H   Avg of Test  Avg of H    
2               2           30          50         15           25
```

By doing this:

The `Sum Test`is calculated using `=SUMIF(B1:E1;"Test *";B2:E2)` and the `No. of Tests`is calculated using `=COUNTIF(B1:E1;"Test *")` (to get the number of `Test`in the header range).

The `Avg of...`is just the simple division of "Sum of" and "No. of" values.

Of course you will have to adjust the range used to match the actual range of values in the header and value rows.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using AVERAGEIF which seems to give me the correct values. Because It has three qualifiers the first most importantly is the range which I can reference the headers and then I can provide the criteria so where header is "H*" etc and then the rows to calculate the average.

This is the formula that I used:

=AVERAGEIF(Table1[[#Headers],[HM1]:[HM3]],"H*",Table1[@[HM1]:[HM3]])

Now I just need to work on a count which is similar to the above!

Just a further update to this. I managed to also work out the count using the COUNTIFS function. What I didn't realise originally was the IFS were inclusive so it included the first IF AND the second IF.

This is the formula I eventually used:

=COUNTIFS(Table1[#Headers],"H*",Table1[@[HM1]:[HM3]],">0")

Thanks All.